# Delete or undo Buffalo resource generation

Tags: go, buffalo

I have generated a resource in Buffalo using the command:

```
buffalo g resource <name> <flags>
```

I have realized I have made a mistake in this resource generation, how do I

- Undo the generation of the resource?
- Remove/Destroy the resource?

I do not see this in Buffalo's documentation or the `buffalo g resource --help` message.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the destroy cli, fortunately there is a `destroy resource` command to help, you can do something like:

`buffalo d resource <name>`

And it will guide you on which things to remove, or you could pass the --yes flag to simply remove all associated files. p.e:

`buffalo d resource <name> --yes`

or

`buffalo d resource <name> -y`